# importing from shared module

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I have a folder structure as follows

```
mainDirectory/
|_expoApp/
   |_App.js
|_shared/
   |_utils.js
```

Inside `App.js` I try to import from `shared/utils.js` with `import {SomeClass} from "../shared/utils";`

However, I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve "../shared/utils" from "App.js"
Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

So far, I've tried including a `package.js` file to the shared folder and then including it as a dependancy in expoApp's package.js but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Does anyone know how to import from shared folder correctly?

Comment: Try adding the `.js` file extension. Some module resolution algorithms need it.

Comment: nope, adding .js didn't work

Comment: according to your folder structure `import {SomeClass} from "../shared/utils";` is absolutely correct. Now only problem could be, import takes absolute path in your case instead of relative path. check your project if you have set up absolute path somewhere. https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d

Answer (score 0):

In the dependencies of  "expoApp" folder,  add in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"shared": "file:../shared/utils/"
}
```

Using:

```
import some from shared;
```

Comment: Please change to file:.../